# String cannot be resolved java

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, random

I'm trying to make a 12 by 12 table which consists of different random letters, but the user can choose if it will consist of 4 different letters, 3 or 2...however i'm getting an error that the string cannot be resolved and i don't know why...Please help...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
public class PlayingArea {
public static void main(String[] args){
int N = letters.length();//error here "letters cannot be resolved"
    Random r = new Random(); 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("How many regions would you like (2- 4)");
    int region = input.nextInt();
    if (region == 4){
        String letters= "EFGH"; 
    }
    if (region == 3){
        String letters= "EFG"; 
    }
    else if (region == 2){
        String letters= "EF"; 
    }
    else { System.out.println("You inputed a wrong value, try again...");

    }
    char [][] letter = new char[12][12]; 


    for (int j = 0; j < letter.length; j++){

        for(int i=0; i < letter.length; i++) {
            letter[i][j] = letters.charAt(r.nextInt(N)) ; 
        }
    }       

    for (char[] letterRow : letter) 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letterRow)); //error here "letters cannot be resolved"       
}
```

}

Comment: where is the error occurring?

Comment: what is `letters`? I don't see any `letters` `String` initialization. I think you are getting NPE.

Comment: Post the entire error/exception text, including stack trace.

Comment: here:     int N = letters.length();
and:     letter[i][j] = letters.charAt(r.nextInt(N)) ;

Comment: `letters` is not declared or initialized before it is used.

Comment: @tintinmj: I guess he's not even compiling that code but referring to some error message the IDE displays there. That's why he isn't referring to an NPE but something about resolving a string.

Comment: (1) `letters` string  is not defined when you try to retrieve its length. (2) after `else` part of your `if`, `letters` is **still** not defined.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis more specifically, it is declared (and hence scoped) wihtin the if statements at the top. http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Comment: Excuse me for asking..but how exactly should i define it to work in this case??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line causing the error and do it like this instead:

```
String letters;

if (region == 4){
    letters= "EFGH"; 
}
if (region == 3){
    letters= "EFG"; 
}
else if (region == 2){
    letters= "EF"; 
}
else { 
    System.out.println("You inputed a wrong value, try again...");
}
int N = letters.length();
```

The reason you are getting an error is because letters does not exist yet so you cannot call `letters.length()` where you do.  You should be getting a NullPointerException.

I would also recommend handling a user not inputting 2, 3, or 4, as the code will just reach an error anyway.  You could put your if/else statements in a while loop while `letters.length() < 2` for instance:

```
String letters = "";
while(letters.length() < 2) {
    if (region == 4){
        letters= "EFGH"; 
    }
    if (region == 3){
        letters= "EFG"; 
    }
    else if (region == 2){
        letters= "EF"; 
    }
    else { 
        System.out.println("You inputed a wrong value, try again...");
    }
}
int N = letters.length();
```

Perhaps you can find a better condition, but that should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the help turbo :D it runs perfectly now.

Comment: @Tommon If this answer was helpful to you, please accept it by clicking the check mark under the score to the top left of the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

your letters string is out of scope. Try initializing it before you set it.

```
if (region == 4){
    String letters= "EFGH"; 
}
System.out.println(letters.charAt(0));
```

will produce an error because letters is defined within the scope of the if statement. To make it available outside of the if you want the following.

```
String letters = "";
if (region == 4){
    letters= "EFGH"; 
}
System.out.println(letters.charAt(0));
```